# Отредактировать регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть код:

```
echo preg_replace('/#(\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b)/iu', '<a href="#">#$1</a>', '#11  #f1 #1f #ff');
```

Как сделать, чтобы теги #11 (#только цифры), не превращались в ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
echo preg_replace('/#([0-9]*?([a-z]+[0-9]*)+)/i', '<a href="#">#$1</a>', '#11  #f1 #1f #ff');
```

Answer (score 0):

зачем так сложно, все ж просто

```
echo preg_replace('/#(?!\d++\b)\w+/iu', '<a href="#">$0</a>', '#11  #f1 #1f #ff ddd #22aa c #0');
//result #11 <a href="#">#f1</a> <a href="#">#1f</a> <a href="#">#ff</a> ddd <a href="#">#22aa</a> c #0
```